# Trimming leading 0's in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
 SUBSTRING(str_col, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', str_col+'.'), LEN(str_col))
```

I am unable to understand why '.' is done in the code. It works well even if we omit '.' part. If anyone can throw light on this. Thank you!

Comment: It is a "Fail-Safe"   so the patindex() won't return a zero

Answer (score 1):

The `+ '.'` ensures that at least one character matches the pattern.

Otherwise, the code will not work on a string that consists only of `'0'`s.